# Modify request in middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, filter, request, middleware

I have a TrimInput middleware registrated as a middleware for my routes to trim all user input before the request hits the controller. Within the middleware the trimming seems working, but when I dump the request in the action the request seems unmodified like there was no middleware before.

<del>What's the problem here?</del> The problem is the ClientRequest but why?

```
// TrimInput.php
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TrimInput {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $request->replace($this->trimArrayRecursive($request->all()));
        // When I dump $request right here, all seems fine (the input is trimmed)

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function trimArrayRecursive($input) {
        if (!is_array($input)) {
            return trim($input);
        }

        return array_map([$this, 'trimArrayRecursive'], $input);
    }

}


// Somwhere in my routes.php
Route::post('/test', ['middleware' => 'trim', 'uses' => function(\App\Http\Requests\ClientRequest $request) {
    dd($request->all()); // Unfortunately dumps the unfiltered (untrimmed) input
}]);
```

**EDIT:** It turned out, that the above code is working, but unfortunately my `ClientRequest` ignores the `TrimInputMiddleware`.

```
// ClientRequest.php
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

class ClientRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        $idToIgnore = $this->input('id');

        return [
            'name'           => 'required|max:255|unique:clients,name,' . $idToIgnore,
            'street'         => 'required|max:255',
            'postal_code'    => 'required|digits:5',
            'city'           => 'required|max:255',
            'contact_person' => 'required|max:255'
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: I've verified this on fresh L5 install and I'm getting trimmed input. Maybe you should try to run `php artisan clear-compiled` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I just tried it and it didn't work. Could you put your working code to pastebin?

Comment: I also have this problem, I'm on 5.2, if I use Request Facade, the input gets modified and propagated to the controller, but when I inject my own request, it just gets the full unprocessed input.
I can notice that when in the middleware, there's an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Request`, but in the end you are calling the `all()` method from a `App\Http\Requests\ClientRequest`. I guess this has something to do, but I don't know how to solve it. Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 1):

You should first assign the middleware a short-hand key in your **app/Http/Kernel.php** file. like below

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'trim' => 'App\Http\Middleware\TrimInput ',
];
```

Comment: If he's dumping the middleware and that's showing up, then it must be running as part of the request, so one would assume he's already done the above, otherwise it wouldn't work with the way he has set up his routing.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the middleware to and modify the request input on `FormRequest`, you need to overwrite it using the `all()` method on `/app/Http/Requests/Request.php` because it's loaded before the middleware is executed. This was fixed in Laravel 5.4 I believe.

Here's what worked for me. Add this method in Request.php and it will apply the changes done in your middleware.

```
public function all()
{
    $this->merge( $this->request->all() );

    return parent::all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the framework's Illuminate\Foundation\Http/Middleware\TrimStrings.php
middleware and add it to your `web` middleware group